# GridView swaps items

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, baseadapter, android-gridview

Hello my friends I have a problem. When I scroll down in my GridView and scroll up the order of the items changes. I want all itmes to stay on the same place. Below you can find my code. It would be nice if someone can help me out as this is a very irritating bug.

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    private final String [] data;
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int[] i = {
        R.drawable.blue,
        R.drawable.green,
        R.drawable.yellow,
    };

    public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = new View(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item,null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n = rand.nextInt(i.length);
            imageView.setImageResource(i[n]);
            textView.setText(data[position]);
        }else{
           view = (View)convertView;
        }

        return view;
    } }
```

Comment: `getItem()` probably shouldn't just be returning `position`. It should be returning `data[position]`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
to faster the performance use ViewHolder like below
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);  
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(imageView, textView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  n = rand.nextInt(i.length);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(i[n]);
    viewHolder.textView.setText(data[position]);
    return convertView;
} 
 private class ViewHolder {
    private final TextView imageView;
    private final TextView textView;
    public ViewHolder(TextView imageView, TextView textView) {
      this.imageView = imageView;
      this.textView = textView;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks but your code made the scrolling very laggy and then all items in the gridview disappeared when i scrolled a little bit faster

Comment: Try using a view holder.

Comment: I modified the answer. Please recheck again @Faith Gee

Comment: thank you it is now a little bit faster but it is still totally messing up the gridview when I am scrolling

Comment: actually my soulution is working good just the items need to be placed on their original positions like it was at the beginning. I have read that it is recycling internally the items to save memory but why the hell is it not drawing the items at their original positions.  I could not figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after adding those 2 lines:

@Override

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}
```